# Is there a way to start a method in fragment B when i partialy navigated from fragment A?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments (tab fragments), A and B. Is there a way to detect when i partialy swipe from A to B to start an async task in B? I want to update the fragment B similar to what Facebook android app is doing (there you got fragment A and when you start swiping to fragment B you see it updating. If its not possible with fragments what are my other options? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using a ViewPager for your tab fragment layout. The method you're looking for is in viewPager.OnPageChangedListener.
Here is the reference:
[ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

I give you an example:

```
myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
                                                Log.d("onPageScrolled","position: " + i + "-posOffset: " + v + "-pixOffset " + i2);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onPageSelected(int i) {

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
                                                Log.d("onPageScrollState","changed");
                                            }
                                        });
```

In particular, the method onPageScrolled is called many times during a page scroll (you should verify your Async Task is called only once, with the parameters v and i2)

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the method i was looking for, now my fragments have the desired behavior.